# scanf mathematic expression in c

Tags: c, scanf

I'm a beginner in the c language learning and I have a question.
I have to write the following code: user enters a mathematical expression for example `2+3*7` and the code should send the result and take into account the priority of the `*` and the `/`.

I thought to enter the user's expression into a char array (**it is forbidden to use string**) in the first step.

```
int counter=0;
char test[50],input;

while (counter < 50 && scanf("%c", &input) != EOF ){
    test[counter] = input;
    counter++;
}

for (i = 0; i < counter; i++){
    printf("%c ", test[i]);
}
```

But the code didn't exit of the loop when the user does enter.  What is wrong?
My second question is if it is a good idea to enter the expression into char array if I can not use string?
I can obtain all the characters of the expression in this way?

Comment: It won't exit if a user hits enter because hitting enter produces the newline character `\n` which is a valid character to assign and thus scanf will return 1 and the condition will still be true. `fgets` would be a better solution here :).

Comment: If she cannot use strings then she cannot use `fgets()`.  Presumably that is part of the point of the exercise.

Comment: I think clarification is required as to what you are and aren't allowed to use. "strings" aren't really a thing in `c`.

Comment: @Samidamaru, C strings are not a separate data type from arrays of `char`, but inasmuch as the standard describes syntax and semantics for "string literals" and discusses other aspects of strings, I don't think one can support the proposition that "'strings' aren't really a thing in c".

Comment: "[is it] a good idea to enter the expression into char array if I can not use string?" It is unclear whether that would violate the conditions of the exercise, but I'm having trouble seeing how you could use a `char` array in a manner that is both non-string-like and more helpful to you than the alternatives.

Comment: Note: better to test of what is acceptable rather than against a sample unacceptable value.  `scanf("%c", &input) != EOF` --> `scanf("%c", &input) == 1`.  (It will not make a functional difference with `"%c"`  though.)

Comment: "forbidden to use string)" and "... if I can not use string?" implies code cannot use `scanf("%c", &input)` as `"%c"` is a string.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't use fgets, in the class we learned at the array and functions chapter. I can't use the string.h library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the code didn't exit of the loop when the user does enter.

If you want the loop to break after ENTER key, you have to check that in your condition:

```
while (counter < 50 && scanf("%c", &input) != EOF && input != '\n' ) {
...
}
```

> My second question is if it is a good idea to enter the expression
>   into char array if I can not use string?

Yes. It's fine. There's little difference between a C-string and a char array (such as the terminating NUL byte). So if you can't use string/line reading functions such as `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);` or `scanf("%s", buf);`, then you don't have too many choices.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that whether using a char array is acceptable when strings are not acceptable is a question that can be answered only by whoever assigned the exercise.  My own guess would be "no", but I'm no more authoritative on that than anyone else here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger My guess is that the purpose of this exercise is to make OP to read char-by-char rather than easier way of using `fgets()` and learn about EOF, loops, terminating condition for the loop etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added to my while &&input != '\n' but it didn't work again ...

Comment: It is forbidden to use the string.h library so I think I can use the char array. I doesn't see an another solution to my problem ... I have to enter the operation signs into the array too

Comment: @Juliette I don't see why it wouldn't work. Your code works for me. See here: http://ideone.com/3vwJps

Comment: It works thanks!!!!! I had a buffer problem with scanf, it is the reason why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 1):

> But the code didn't exit of the loop when the user does enter.

You're code doesn't exit the loop until it gets an EOF(which would typically mean the user presses Ctrl+D) or 50 characters have been entered, not on enter. If you want to end when the user presses enter you need to check if the last character input was a newline.

Also, if you are reading one character at a time `getchar` would probably be better than scanf.

Reading into a char array is fine, as long as you don't get more characters than the size of the buffer at a time, and make sure that you never overflow the buffer.

*EDIT*

Somewhat tongue-in-cheek, if the requirement that you can't use strings just means you can't use string.h, and whitespace isn't allowed in the expression (so "4+5" is valid but "4 + 5" isn't), you could just do this:

```
char test[51],input;
scanf("%50s" &input);
printf("%s", input);
```

The extra char in `test` is for the null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing `scanf()` for `EOF` which is a test for error or end of file, otherwise `scanf()` returns the number of fields matching the format strings successfully converted.  In this case it cannot fail when the input is from the console since `%c` will match any character, and `scanf()` will wait indefinitely on the console if there is no character present - You can inject an EOF into the console input, but it seems unlikely that this is intended in this case.

`scanf()` is not necessary here, the simpler `getchar()` will suffice:

```
do
{
    input = getchar() ;
    test[counter] = input;
    counter++;

} while( counter < sizeof(test) && input != '\n' ) ;
```

Note that like your original code, this does not add a nul terminator (so in that sense it is not a "string").

---

Due to somewhat irrational restrictions on what parts of stdio may apparently be used:

```
do
{
    scanf( "%c", &input ) ;
    test[counter] = input;
    counter++;

} while( counter < sizeof(test) && input != '\n' ) ;
```

Comment: `scanf()` *does* return `EOF` if the input was terminated by `Ctrl-Z` (Windows) and possibly by `Ctrl-D` (Linux).

Comment: @WeatherVane : True, but do you expect such arcane knowledge from your user?  It seems that the requirement is to read a single line of input.

Comment: No, but I expect it from you. You made a categorical statement about `EOF`, I was just qualifying it. If I make the sole entry `Ctrl-Z` the return value from `scanf` is not `0`

Comment: @WeatherVane : Sorry - I agree, my response was not intended to be as terse as it now looks.  Moreover I dis say it was "invalid" and it is clearly not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't use getchar() I don't learn it in class. I have a question: what does mean in your condition != '\n'?

Comment: Interesting that you would learn scanf() before getchar().  It would be a more effective teaching method to allow students to use specific parts of the standard library and allow them to work from the documentation rather then just what has been taught.

Comment: @Juliette : Not everything you read on the internet is necessarily accurate or correct! ;-)  I fixed the code `input != '\n'` - not equal to <newline>

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to write a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). You could first have some [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) (giving a stream of tokens from a stream of characters). Then from a stream of tokens, your parser would either build an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) in memory, or it could (in your simple case of expressions without variables) compute the expression during the parsing. Any good book about compilers (e.g. the [dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)) explain that in great details.

Several tools exist to generate parsers & lexers. They are (pompously) called [compiler-compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) (but they should really be called parser generators). GNU [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) is such a tool. But you could consider [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (probably some older version, [ANTLR2](http://www.antlr2.org/) or PCCTS)

What you want to achieve is a very standard exercise. There is an [example (`calc`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html) given in documentation of `bison`; and the [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) wikipage has also very similar code.

Regarding `scanf`  specifically, read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) & [getchar(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html) (and also `ungetc`....). You might read an entire line (to parse it easier and later) with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (or perhaps even [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) on the terminal) or else [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html)...

Comment: This addresses the exercise Juliette has been asked to solve; but that is *not* the question she has asked.  The question is only about accepting the user input.

Answer (score 0):

> But the code didn't exit of the loop when the user does enter.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` is a valid `char` to read with `scanf("%c", &input)`.  It is simply read just like `'2'` and `'+'`.

> My second question is if it is a good idea to enter the expression into char array if I can not use string?

Yes this is reasonable.  Code needs to 1) not store `char` past array size 2) Keep track of the used elements in the array.

> I can obtain all the characters of the expression in this way?

If you cannot use *stings*, perhaps you cannot use `"%c"`.  Use `fgetc(),fputc()`

```
#define N 50
int counter=0;
char test[N];
int input;  // use int to distinguish EOF from a character.

while (counter < N && (input = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && input != EOF) {
  test[counter] = input;
  counter++;
}

for (i = 0; i < counter; i++){
  fputc(test[i], stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that C does not have a `string` data type *per se*; in C, a *string* is simply a sequence of character values terminated by a 0-valued byte (or byte sequence for multi-byte strings).  Strings are *stored* as arrays of `char`, but not every array of `char` contains a string.

If you just want to get a sequence of characters from standard input into a buffer for further parsing, this is probably the simplest approach:

```
char buffer[N]; // where N is large enough for one line's worth of input;
                // let's call it 80 for now.

while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) )
{
  // process buffer
}
```

`fgets` will read characters from the standard input stream into `buffer` until it either sees a newline (which it will store into `buffer` if there's room), or has read `sizeof buffer - 1` characters.  `fgets` will always write a 0 byte to the buffer to terminate the string.  So, for example, if your buffer is sized to hold 10 characters and you type in "2 + 3 * 4<kbd>Enter</kbd>", then `buffer` will contain `{'2', ' ', '+', ' ', '3', ' ', '*', ' ', '4', 0}`; there isn't enough room to store the newline character, but the string is 0-terminated.

`fgets` will return `NULL` if it can't read input from the stream, so the loop above will run until there's a read error or until `fgets` detects an EOF condition.

However...

The usual approach for handling a situation like this is to read a character at a time from the input and process as you go; this way you don't have to worry about setting aside a buffer large enough to hold the entire expression, you only need buffers large enough to handle *tokens* within the larger expression (numbers and operators).